# Cannot get currentUser after custom Drupal boot

Tags: 8, bootstrapping

I have a `/foo.php` on the Drupal 8 root which programmatically boots Drupal:

```
chdir('web');
$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
print_r($request->cookies);             // ... ( ... ( [SSESSabfa7...] => _Eu_28jS3Vr8Y... ))
$this->kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$this->kernel->boot();
var_dump(\Drupal::currentUser()->id()); // int(0)

$this->kernel->preHandle($request);
var_dump(\Drupal::currentUser()->id()); // int(0)
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be able to access the current user (see the `var_dump`s). By visiting a regular Drupal URL though (e.g at `/` or `/about`) I confirm that the session cookie is correct with a logged in user.

What do I need to do so my custom PHP script boots Drupal in a way that it can return the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to authenticate the user. This is what a normal Drupal request would do as one of the first things after the kernel is booted:

*Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\AuthenticationSubscriber*

```
public function onKernelRequestAuthenticate(RequestEvent $event) {
  if ($event->isMainRequest()) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($this->authenticationProvider->applies($request)) {
      $account = $this->authenticationProvider->authenticate($request);
      if ($account) {
        $this->accountProxy->setAccount($account);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adapting this to the procedural code:

*web/foo.php*

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
print_r($request->cookies);             // ... ( ... ( [SSESSabfa7...] => _Eu_28jS3Vr8Y... ))
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->boot();
$kernel->preHandle($request);

$container = $kernel->getContainer();
// Ensure our request includes the session.
$request->setSession($container->get('session'));
// Authenticate the user, see AuthenticationSubscriber::onKernelRequestAuthenticate().
$account = $container->get('authentication')->authenticate($request);
if ($account) {
  $container->get('current_user')->setAccount($account);
}

var_dump(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```

Comment: And if you are behind a TLS terminating proxy, where cookie is `Secure`, you also need `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';`.

Comment: Yes, depending on the use case you might need one or more of the things Drupal handles in middlewares. My code already contains replacements for the KernelPreHandle and Session middlewares. You add now what normally ReverseProxyMiddleware would do.