# How do I bootstrap from my /app.php without `Page not found`

Tags: 8, bootstrapping

#### Introduction

There are lots of [bootstrapping](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping) questions **and** answers on how to bootstrap but I haven't found how to not get **Page not found** watchdog notices. Using these question and answers I came up with this bad solution cut and paste from the actual code.

#### `/app`

Assuming Drupal core is located in `./www/core` and my app in `./www/app`

```php
// ./www/app/index.php
// =========== APP SECTION ==================

define('DRUPAL_ROOT_FOR_APP', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('APP_ROOT', __DIR__);

$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$current_dir = getcwd();

// =========== DRUPAL SECTION ==================

// CR https://www.drupal.org/node/2275139
// CR https://www.drupal.org/node/2409067

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// Preserve app settings
$app_settings = [
  'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],
];

// Set drupal context
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = DRUPAL_ROOT_FOR_APP . '/index.php';
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/index.php';

chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT_FOR_APP);
$autoloader = require_once DRUPAL_ROOT_FOR_APP . '/autoload.php';

$kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// This generates page not found <========================
$response = $kernel->handle($request);

$sess = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('session');

// Restore script context
chdir(APP_ROOT);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $app_settings['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = $app_settings['SCRIPT_NAME'];

$user = \Drupal::currentUser();

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryInterface $query */
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');

// =========== APP SECTION ==================

require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/classes/AppDrupalInterface.php';

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

...
```

I think the answer lies in **not using** `$response = $kernel->handle($request);`.

I tried using `$this->kernel->preHandle($request);` mentioned in [Cannot get currentUser after custom Drupal boot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295626/cannot-get-currentuser-after-custom-drupal-boot) but failed that time.

#### Watchdog

Having `./www/app/index.php` request to `/app` leads to **/app** 'Page not found' notices in Drupal watchdog. Same goes for all `/app/**` requests.

#### Question

How do I prevent these notices by changing what part from the code above?

Comment: $kernel->handle() runs a normal Drupal request. Most people understand by *bootstrapping* letting Drupal initialize itself to run a specific function without building an entire Drupal response.

Comment: Note sure what to reply. I said "I think the answer lies in __not using__ $response = $kernel->handle($request);."

Comment: OK, the logged error goes away then which is caused by passing a request not containing a routable URL. Other than that the referenced CR applies, without the deprecated [prepareLegacyRequest](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3AprepareLegacyRequest/8.9.x) and the comment proposing handle(). So I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I've updates some parts and added directory locations + a real question to the end. Hope that helps

Comment: Running a Drupal request and then throwing away the response is like cheating. Bootstrapping in the scope of the tag you've referenced is exactly the opposite, applying only selected methods on the Drupal kernel so that you have a much smaller footprint, for example like only 10 % of a normal request.